# MVC3 Plugin architecture recommendations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to find some more information on approaches to creating a plugin architecture.

I've seen some good articles on MEF and MVC2 and Phil Haack mentioned some new extensibilty hooks available in MVC3 (http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx)

Has anyone seen some good references on creating a plugin architecture for a MVC3 project?

I'd prefer to use technologies specific to MVC3, not to just hack a MVC2 solution in to the MVC2 framework.

Any ideas and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Al, "Any ideas and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!"  People have gone to the trouble of answering; I'm sure they'd appreciate it if you accepted an answer (assuming there's a suitable one).

Answer (score 6):

We're using a combination of [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) [Portable Areas](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20a%20Portable%20Area&referringTitle=Documentation) and [Mono.Addins](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Addins) for our plugin framework.

It is working wonderfully.

Comment: +1 - including actual practices in use is definately helpful to the OP

Comment: Why the downvote? Would really like people to have to justify it, even as anon.  If nothing else it could help improve the answer quality.

Answer (score 4):

I just published an article about my own plugin system which is based on regular MVC3 Areas.

http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-mvccontrib-the-plugin-system/

You can even edit plugin views at runtime and see the changes directly in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think all the techniques that were valid for MVC 1 and 2 are now "hacks" for 3?

There are probably 10 different architectures listed in these search results that would accomplish what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[asp.net-mvc]+plugins

Comment: jfar -in fariness, i don't think the OP said anything of the sort (What makes you think all the techniques that were valid for MVC 1 and 2 are now "hacks" for 3?). what he said was: I'd prefer to use technologies specific to MVC3, not to just hack a MVC2 solution in to the MVC2 framework. this is quite different :)

Answer (score 0):

MVC 3 is the same basic architecture as MVC 2 and MVC 1 before it.  Each new version of MVC merely adds a few new features, or makes a slight change to previous component.

If you find a solution for an earlier version of MVC, it will likely work quite well in whatever the latest version happens to be at the time, or with very minor changes.